# Global variable doesn't store any data in anonymous method

Tags: ios, json, swift

trying to get nasa.gov asteroid's data. There is a `asteroids` global variable of array of Asteroid instances. There is about 1000 occurrences in the `jsonData` variable. When I append the occurrence at the line `self.asteroids.append()`, I can see it's adding. When the anonymous `completionHandler` method ends, variable `self.asteroids` is empty again, so it doesn't reload no data.

It doesn't make any sense to me since `asteroids` is a global variable and it should store any data appended to it. Can anyone help?

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var asteroids = [Asteroid]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let connectionString: String = "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json"
    let url = NSURL(string: connectionString)!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
            for index in 0 ... (jsonData.count - 1) {
                self.asteroids.append(Asteroid(name: jsonData[index]["name"] as! NSString as String))
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
    })

    task.resume()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the table view's reloadData method in the completion block, after the asteroids array has been modified.
Another way would be to reloadData in `asteroid` didSet method:

```
var asteroids = [Asteroid]() {
  didSet {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```

Code of the completion handler is called after the end of scope of viewDidLoad function. Because the dataTaskWithURL is an asynchronous operation.

Comment: I've tried both solutions. The solution with reloading data in the `completionBlock` does not work, TableViewController does not show any rows when I ran the simulator. The second solution with `didSet` does work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it empty or you're reloading the table view *before* the dataTask finishes?

Try to move the reloadData inside the completion closure:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let connectionString: String = "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json"
    let url = NSURL(string: connectionString)!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
            for index in 0 ... (jsonData.count - 1) {
                self.asteroids.append(Asteroid(name: jsonData[index]["name"] as! NSString as String))
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
    })

    task.resume()

}
```

**UPDATE**: A second approach, if you're 100% sure you want the tableView to be updated **after** all data has been downloaded & parsed could be:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let connectionString: String = "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json"
    let url = NSURL(string: connectionString)!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
            for index in 0 ... (jsonData.count - 1) {
                self.asteroids.append(Asteroid(name: jsonData[index]["name"] as! NSString as String))
            }
            self.tableView.delegate = self
            self.tableView.dataSource = self

        } catch {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
    })

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: It does work, but I have to make a move in the simulator (e.g. click in the table, make a multi-touch scroll). Isn't there any possibility to make it implicitly appear when the simulator is started?

Comment: In your case, if you want the TableView to load data when the task is finished, and you don't plan to reload it, you can also set the delegate & datasource references to the ViewController (assuming is a UITableViewController or you're conforming to UITableViewDelegate / Datasource protocols). Will update answer